# jQuery click event works only once while toggling the sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a sidebar, but it works only once. I think the query code is self explanatory. Though I can write the HTML code if you want.

```
    $('.side-menu').on('click', function(){
        $('.control-sidebar').addClass('active-sidebar');
        $('.side-menu').on('click', function(){
            $('.control-sidebar').removeClass('active-sidebar');
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you can provide a sample we can help easily. Try [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean code solution would look somehow like this:

```
$('.side-menu').on('click', function(){
    $('.control-sidebar').toggleClass('active-sidebar');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic is not right in your case.

```
if(!$('.control-sidebar').hasClass('active-sidebar')){...}
```

This code will run when class "control-sidebar" don't have class "active-sidebar".

at the beginning, the case happens so you can click on .side-menu and add class "active-sidebar" to DOM. this against your first logic.

Moreover, why this happens twice in your code?

```
$('.side-menu').on('click', function(){...}
```

Solution:
 Use toggle class: see this https://jsfiddle.net/BeklievParviz/rwnpk0wm/

Comment: yes. I think I should change it. Lets me check if it helps.

Comment: It is not working that way as well. I have changed the code in the question. Also I'm adding the class in the first function, and removing it in the other that is why I am checking the click event twice.

Comment: Could you plz show your new code again? @ujjwalverma

Comment: I have got the solution of the problem. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.side-menu').on('click', function(){
    $('.control-sidebar').toggleClass('active-sidebar');
});
```

User This